# Best way to send float values over BLE

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to send quaternions (4 float values) over BLE to the client in one Bluetooth characteristic. My concern is to find the fastest and least computational demanding way of passing that data.

Up to now, I was using `sprintf()` to concatenate float values and push them to `setValue()` but I wasn't able to decode the output bytes on the client-side. I was thinking to send the values as an int and then parse them back to float on the client-side. What would you recommend as the best solution?

Code on the Server side:

```
 if (deviceConnected) {

    readQuatData(BNO055_quatCount);

        BNO055_quat[0] = (float)(BNO055_quatCount[0]) / 16384.;
        BNO055_quat[1] = (float)(BNO055_quatCount[1]) / 16384.;
        BNO055_quat[2] = (float)(BNO055_quatCount[2]) / 16384.;
        BNO055_quat[3] = (float)(BNO055_quatCount[3]) / 16384.;

sprintf(myConcatenation, "%3.2f %3.2f %3.2f %3.2f", BNO055_quat[0] , BNO055_quat[1], BNO055_quat[2], BNO055_quat[3]);

pCharacteristic->setValue(myConcatenation);

      pCharacteristic->notify(); // Send the value to the app!
}
```

These are the possible inputs to the `SetValue()` function:

```
void BLECharacteristic::setValue(std::string value) {
        setValue((uint8_t*)(value.data()), value.length());
} // setValue

void BLECharacteristic::setValue(uint16_t& data16) {
    uint8_t temp[2];
    temp[0] = data16;
    temp[1] = data16 >> 8;
    setValue(temp, 2);
} // setValue

void BLECharacteristic::setValue(uint32_t& data32) {
    uint8_t temp[4];
    temp[0] = data32;
    temp[1] = data32 >> 8;
    temp[2] = data32 >> 16;
    temp[3] = data32 >> 24;
    setValue(temp, 4);
} // setValue

void BLECharacteristic::setValue(int& data32) {
    uint8_t temp[4];
    temp[0] = data32;
    temp[1] = data32 >> 8;
    temp[2] = data32 >> 16;
    temp[3] = data32 >> 24;
    setValue(temp, 4);
} // setValue

 void BLECharacteristic::setValue(float& data32) {
    uint8_t temp[4];
    *((float*)temp) = data32;
    setValue(temp, 4);
} // setValue

void BLECharacteristic::setValue(double& data64) {
    uint8_t temp[8];
    *((double*)temp) = data64;
    setValue(temp, 8);
} // setValue
```

Comment: The only setValue overload you are using, is missing. `setValue(const char*)`. But that's anyway not the _best_ way, regarding your demand. Obviously there's also a `setValue((uint8_t*)BNO055_quat,32);`

Comment: If you are using Arduino, by default, its `sprintf()` implementation does not support floating point. If you are using platformIO as your IDE, you can add `build_flags` to add floating point support. See my [blog](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/01/do-you-know-arduino-sprintf-and-floating-point/) for the details.